# Visual Basic 6 sql error

Tags: sql, vb6

I am trying to insert a user into my database using the following insert statement

```
insert into [user] (username,password,idnumber,address,phonenumber,isAdmin,vehicleid) values ('Langton','123456','63-222-78393','3 where reaod who','999300324',False,0)
```

But when I run the code it tells me there is a syntax error in my insert statement, what could be the problem.

Comment: Did you try executing it manually?

Comment: Parameterise your queries

Comment: can you try the statement in your SQL serverstudio (if you are using MSSQL).

Comment: how do I go about doing that?

Comment: Show your code that builds the sql and executes it

Answer (score 1):

Hi
You missed the quotes for 'False'

Comment: Try after providing single quotes

Comment: Hi, that column is not a string, rather its a boolean, and really its still not working even after single quotes

Comment: @Shady3cho, If by boolean you mean bit then False should be 0 and True should be 1.

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies with your vehicleid, this has to have a value and '0' is an incorrect number for a record/field. Change this to '1' or more.